# golf-me: your new command-line code-golf companion!

Tags: app, questions, node.js

**Golf-me** is a quick and dirty terminal application you can use to pick out a programming puzzle from Stack Exchange's [*Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

#### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

#### About

I built golf-me because I wanted a quick command-line way to select a challenge that I felt like doing.

#### License

[MIT.](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Download

golf-me is available on npm: `npm install golf-me`

#### Platform

golf-me was developed on Ubuntu Linux, but it *should* work on other *nix platforms and Windows.

#### Contact

My name is John. You can connect with me on github @microwaveabletoaster, twitter @drdikeman, and of course on here @microwaveabletoaster.

#### Code

golf-me is written primarily in CoffeeScript using node. You can [find the source code on Github](https://github.com/microwaveabletoaster/golf-me).